# Repeating contract names in Etherscan

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, etherscan

I was viewing the verified ethereum smart contracts on Etherscan and noticed that a lot of the smart contracts had same names and versions but different contract addresses with varying transaction counts. What does this mean? Does this mean that the contract was deployed several times and the different transaction counts accounts for the transaction made with that specific deployment?

Comment: yes, the contract name is not unique, its instance yes (which is defined by the address). It can be also that two developers have been using the same name without knowing each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contract behaves a bit like an account (or wallet, or call it as you want). Once deployed, it has an ethereum address. It can send/receive ether. The difference is that it can execute code.

The code does not matter. The name can be repeated thousands times on the chain, the chain does not care because it uses the address to identify it.

So basically, yes, you can deploy the same contract again and again. But in a public chain, I think it will cost you more than it gives you money!

Comment: @Ismael Well, actualy, the name is in the code, so... :D